# Conect to mini printer ZEBRA iMZ320 and nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular, zebra-printers

I would like to connect a ZEBRA printer in bluetooth insecure mode. I followed the documentation but I cant `write`.

The firts thing I did was import all `.jar` libraries needed:

[image: List of folders]

In my `ticket.component.ts` first of all:

```
declare var com: any
```

Now, I can access to the `.jar`, so I try this for print:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let bluetooth = new Bluetooth()
    bluetooth
      .enable()
      .then(enableb => {
        this.thePrinterConn = new com.zebra.sdk.comm.BluetoothConnectionInsecure(
          "AC:3F:A3:51:D2:12"
        )

        this.thePrinterConn.open()

        // This sends down JSON to the status channel to retrieve the 'appl.name'
        // setting
        let firmwareVersion = new com.zebra.sdk.printer.SGD.GET(
          "appl.name",
          this.thePrinterConn
        )

        console.log("The firmware version is : ", firmwareVersion)

        let str = "^XA^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FD Works! ZPL^FS^XZ"

        var bytesv2 = [] // char codes

        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
          var code = str.charCodeAt(i)

          bytesv2 = bytesv2.concat([code & 0xff, (code / 256) >>> 0])
        }

        // 72, 0, 101, 0, 108, 0, 108, 0, 111, 0, 220, 122
        console.log("bytesv2", bytesv2)

        // Send the data to printer as a byte array.
        try {
          this.thePrinterConn.write(bytesv2)

          // Make sure the data got to the printer before closing the connection
          setTimeout(() => {
            // Close the insecure connection to release resources.
            console.log("Close")
            this.thePrinterConn.close()
          }, 1000)
        } catch (error) {
          throw error
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        this.thePrinterConn.close()
      })
  }
```

But I get this error:

> JS: Error: Cannot convert array to Ljava/io/InputStream; at index 0

[Docs from zebra](https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/android/content/index.html?overview-summary.html)

## Edit

Apparently works if I convert `bytestv2` with this lines:

```
 var byteArr = Array.create("byte", bytesv2.length)

        let contador = 0
        bytesv2.forEach(x => {
          byteArr[contador] = x
          contador++
        })
```

Found in [nativescript docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js#array-of-objects)

But the printer only feed paper.

Comment: `var bytesv2 = []` is the only array there; isn't there any real stack-trace? I wouldn't be too sure, if `[]` in NativeScript equals the expected `byte[]` (Java) or `ByteArray` (Kotlin).

Comment: If I send the `str` only it sends me the following error: `Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method write on class com.zebra.sdk.comm.ConnectionA`

Comment: I removed that comment, when I seen the method expects `byte[]`. Maybe check the encoding in which the code file is encoded with, because in Java with [`String.getBytes((java.nio.charset.Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)), one can pass the expected `Charset`. I mean, different charsets can lead to different `^` control sequences in ZPL, which may cause wrongful positioning or skipping the characters altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Add the LF and CR to the end of ZPL string to ensure the proper ending

`let str = "^XA^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FD Works! ZPL^FS^XZ\r\n"`

If you only see the paper feed but not the actual print, make sure that printer language is set to ZPL and the media length is set enough to cover the height of the print.

`! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"
! U1 setvar "zpl.label_length" "100"`